# How to delete 12.10 Ubuntu completely

Tags: upgrade

I need a simple guide to completely deleting Ubuntu 12.10 from my laptop in order to install the latest 20.04.2.0 LTS.  I am not an IT fundi and I need a simple guide that I can follow.

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop, and install 20.04 in the same drive 12.10 was installed. Note that your computer may not have the [resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) to smoothly run 20.04. In that case, use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: You don't delete a prior OS, you just install over it.

Comment: Also FYI:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu, it's the *third* latest release of Ubuntu (not the *latest* at all unless you only count LTS releases).

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359387/upgrade-12-10-to-20-04-2-0lts) a few hours ago and it was closed because there was already an answer. Please don't repeat questions.

Answer (score 1):

## First of take a backup of all your important files and documents.

Then make a bootable pendrive drive of ubuntu 20.04 and boot your laptop with this pendrive via boot menu.

While installation you will be given a three options . In your case they will be like following...

- install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS along with ubuntu 12.04
- erase the disk and install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- something else.

## in your case you have to choose second option.

-- If you want to keep ubuntu 12.04 than try something else but in this case you have to manage your partitions..

## Hope it will help you..